# print dynamic array in c language

Tags: c

i try to get numbers from my user and this is my function,

my function get arr as pointer and set it to a new array and return the counter of the number that i get for printing.

but when i try to print the array i get an ERROR that ther is noting

```
int GetNumber(int *arr)
{
    int n,i=0;
    int *temp;
    temp = (int*)calloc(1,sizeof(int));
    assert(temp);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n != -1)
    {
        i++;
        temp = (int*) realloc(temp,i*sizeof(int));
        assert(temp);
        temp[i-1] = n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    arr = temp;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: You are only modifying the address of the pointer on the current stack frame, not on the calling one. You should use `int **arr` as an argument and realloc using `*arr = realloc(*arr, ...)`, and thus pass a pointer to an int pointer like so: `GetNumber(&the_arr)`

Comment: Do not `realloc` and assign the return to your original variable. If `realloc` fails, the original `temp` is NOT freed and `NULL` is returned and assigned to `temp` causing you to lose the reference to the block of memory pointed to by `temp` creating a memory leak. Instead use a temporary pointer, e.g. `void *t = realloc (temp, i * sizeof *temp); if (t) temp = t;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you modify a local variable.

In C, all arguments are passed "by value", that means the value is copied into the scope of the function. This also happens with your pointer `arr`. If you modify `arr` in the function, this will never affect the caller.

The solution is to pass a pointer to what you want to modify, so your signature should look like:

```
int GetNumber(int **arr)
```

still, this pointer is passed by value, but it points to the other pointer you want to modify.

On a side note, don't cast `void *` in C. It's implicitly convertible to any pointer type.

Comment: Here is a handy link for the `malloc` cast (you will find you need it over-and-over again), [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)